# VLOOKUP returns #N/A although match exists (=A1=B1 == "TRUE")

Tags: excel, error-handling, match, trim, vlookup

I use Google Analytics API to export some data into Excel. Because the API have limits with the number of dimensions and metrics that can be exported at the same time, I have to make this export usind different queries, which are placed into different sheets.

I want to consolidate all this information in just one sheet, so I create (in every sheet) an unique ID with some shared values of each sheet (using concatenate) and do a VLOOKUP to consolidate the data of every sheet into the first sheet. It works like a charm for 99,5% of the data. But there are some IDs which are returning a #N/A, althought I have manually checked if they are exact matching using =B1='Sheet2'!B191, which returns TRUE.

I generate those Unique IDs with =CONCATENATE(TRIM(B1),TRIM(C1),TRIM(D1)...), so I do not believe there are blank spaces preventing the match. I have even pasted those IDs as "value" and I still get those #N/A.

I am not able to find a cause for this rare behaviour!
Agustín

Comment: Would it be possible to see the VLOOKUP formula?

Comment: Of course: =VLOOKUP(B191,'Segunda-Página'!A:H,8,0). I use a spanish version of Excel (it uses ";" as separator, instead ","), but I am used with english formulas.

Comment: Okay, it seems fine there. If the value of B191 is indeed also found in column A of sheet Segunda-Página, I can't find what's wrong and it should in fact work. Unless there are some special characters, like `~` in B191.

Comment: Yes Jerry. Thats a really weird behaviour. I am used to handle with #N/A errors, but this time it is very rare. Even worse: 90% of the IDs which aren´t matching have this structure day_hour_minute_type-of-visitor_source_medium_device_Caceres‎ (Caceres is a spanish city). The other variables change, but city is always Caceres.

Comment: @agustin, can you show us your workbook? (e.g. using https://www.dropbox.com)

Comment: Hi @simoco, thank you for your willingness to help, but pnuts idea helped! Really rare. Thanks you all!

Comment: Yes @pnuts! If you write the answer down, I will mark it as a valid answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-printing characters may give rise to a number of issues, in this case these apparently were resolved by [CLEAN](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Top-ten-ways-to-clean-your-data-2844b620-677c-47a7-ac3e-c2e157d1db19):

> Removes the first 32 nonprinting characters in the 7-bit ASCII code (values 0 through 31) from text.